# Pandas HDFStore concurrent multiple write

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

How to write data to hdfstore file asynchronously.
I tried but getting exception as

> /usr/share/nginx/www/test/59ece246b82453024e2df1ec.h5
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 536, in run
>       result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>       File "hdfExample.py", line 32, in fetch
>       usg = Usage("59ece246b82453024e2df1ec", mode="a", cnt=gcpage)
>       File "hdfExample.py", line 12, in **init**
>       super(Usage, self).**init**(partnerId, mode, cnt=cnt)
>       File "/usr/share/nginx/www/cloudconsolestandalone/cwunite/flask/hdfinterface.py", line 37, in **init**
>       self.dataframe = self.hdfConn.get(self.partnerId)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 671, in get
>       return self._read_group(group)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1348, in _read_group
>       s.infer_axes()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2350, in infer_axes
>       self.get_attrs()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 3188, in get_attrs
>       a.infer(self) for a in self.indexables if not a.is_an_indexable
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1565, in infer
>       new_self.get_attr()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 2168, in get_attr
>       self.set_kind()
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1877, in set_kind
>       self.typ = getattr(self.description, self.cname, None)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1608, in description
>       return self.table.description
>       AttributeError: 'UnImplemented' object has no attribute 'description'
>       Wed Nov  8 15:33:51 2017  failed with AttributeError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
func(*targs, **kargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/file.py", line 134, in close_all
fileh.close()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/file.py", line 2674, in close
self.root._f_close()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/group.py", line 915, in _f_close
self._g_close_descendents()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/group.py", line 879, in _g_close_descendents
node_manager.close_subtree(self._v_pathname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/file.py", line 543, in close_subtree
self._close_nodes(paths, cache.pop)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/file.py", line 518, in _close_nodes
node._f_close()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/table.py", line 2957, in _f_close
self.flush()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/table.py", line 2894, in flush
rowsadded = self.flush_rows_to_index(_lastrow=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/table.py", line 2517, in flush_rows_to_index
if nrows > 0 and not col.index.dirty:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/table.py", line 3332, in index
index = self._table_file._get_node(indexPath)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/file.py", line 1541, in _get_node
node = self._node_manager.get_node(nodepath)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/file.py", line 437, in get_node
node = self.node_factory(key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/group.py", line 1174, in _g_load_child
return ChildClass(self, childname, new=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/index.py", line 399, in __init__
super(Index, self).__init__(parentnode, name, title, new, filters)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/group.py", line 235, in __init__
super(Group, self).__init__(parentnode, name, _log)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/node.py", line 275, in __init__
self._g_post_init_hook()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/index.py", line 453, in _g_post_init_hook
nelementsSLR:nelementsSLR + nboundsLR]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/array.py", line 652, in __getitem__
arr = self._read_slice(startl, stopl, stepl, shape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/array.py", line 756, in _read_slice
self._g_read_slice(startl, stopl, stepl, nparr)
File "tables/hdf5extension.pyx", line 1532, in tables.hdf5extension.Array._g_read_slice (tables/hdf5extension.c:17196)
tables.exceptions.HDF5ExtError: HDF5 error back trace

File "H5Dio.c", line 173, in H5Dread
can't read data
File "H5Dio.c", line 554, in H5D__read
can't read data
File "H5Dchunk.c", line 1875, in H5D__chunk_read
unable to read raw data chunk
File "H5Dchunk.c", line 2905, in H5D__chunk_lock
data pipeline read failed
File "H5Z.c", line 1372, in H5Z_pipeline
filter returned failure during read
File "H5Zdeflate.c", line 125, in H5Z_filter_deflate
inflate() failed
End of HDF5 error back trace
```

Sample code is here:

> class HdfDbInterface(object):
>           def **init**(self, partnerId):
>               self.partnerId = partnerId

```
        if self.partnerId:
            self.hdfStorePath = config.hdfStorePath + str(self.partnerId) + '.h5'
            print self.hdfStorePath

            self.hdfConn = HDFStore(self.hdfStorePath, mode=mode, complevel=9, complib='blosc')
            self.hdfStoreKey = self.partnerId
            if '/' + self.hdfStoreKey in self.hdfConn.keys():
                self.dataframe = self.hdfConn.get(self.partnerId)
            else:
                self.dataframe = DataFrame()

    def bulkInsert(self, doc):

        if not self.partnerId:
            raise ValueError("Login as a user before inserting data.")

        doc.reset_index(inplace=True)
        if "index" in doc.columns:
            doc.drop(['index'], axis=1, inplace=True)

        if len(doc):
            self.hdfConn.put(self.hdfStoreKey, doc, format='table', data_columns=True, append=True, dropna=True)

        return True

objHdf = HdfDbInterface("59f9d1cf4c7c5c0cf6a16cdb")
doc = DataFrame([{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":1,"d":2}])
objHdf.bulkInsert()
```

Please help me to solve my problem
Thanks

Comment: see the big red box: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#caveats

Comment: Jeff, thanks for sending useful link.